# Why won't the Auth Component username & password login automagic work as expected in CakePHP?

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp

I am trying to build the login registration page for my website, I am facing problems with he Auth Component,

```
function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'login');
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'landing');
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'home');

    // These pages do not require authenication<br/>
    $this->Auth->allow('home','register','activate','forgot','reset','_sendEmail','reset');
}
```

I am encrypting and storing the passwords in the database using `$this->Auth->password` method, now even when I log in succesfully I dont get redirected to the landing page under users controller, I tried printing out `$this->Auth` and it says

```
[loginError] => Login failed. Invalid username or password.
[authError] => You are not authorized to access that location.
```

Also in my database the fields against which I am using authentication are email and password, I read somewhere that the AuthComponent requires the fields to be username and password for the automagic to work

I cant figure out what I am doing wrong, also after logging in, if I try to point my browser to http://cake.localhost/users/register it should automatically redirect me to the landing page but it doesnt for some reason.

Any clues as to where I am going wrong?

Shiv

Comment: Can I assume that this is inside app_controller.php? Did you accidentally add this controller as acos for authorization? Then you might have to go and make sure that all groups of users are allowed to view this message.

Comment: This is inside UsersController

Comment: loginAction/loginRedirect/logoutRedirect should be inside app_controller's beforeFilter()..at least, that's what I found as a better design

Comment: yeah no doubt this eliminated some strange errors I was getting

Comment: var $components=array('Auth');even though this is added in the app_controller i am getting error saying Call to undefined method stdClass::allow()
when $components is given in userscontoller then there won't be any error why it happens so???

Answer (score 3):

From the CakePHP cookbook:

> By default, the AuthComponent expects you to have a table called 'users' with fields called 'username' and 'password' to be used.

I wonder if the automagic will work if you're using `email` as the field name?

Try adding this to your beforefilter:

```
function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->fields = array(
        'username' => 'email', 
        'password' => 'password'
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try $this->Auth->allowedActions = array('*'); in the controller's beforeFilter() (not in app_controller).

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this, and this is really a hack was I renamed the form field to password2, then Iin my controller method I set

```
$this->data['password] = $this->data['password2]
```

Then I called

```
$this->Auth->login($this->data)
```

and it seemed to work.
I dont think this is the best way, however it worked and I will go with it till I find a better solution.

Comment: Were you manually encrypting $this->data['password'] before the call before calling $this->Auth->login()?  If so, you're issue is because the login method performs encryption of the password there too, so it's expecting it to be provided in plaintext.

Answer (score 0):

In your app_controller.php

```
function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->fields = array( 'username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password' );
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'login');
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'landing');
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'home');
}
```

In your users controller:

```
function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow(list of your allowed actions);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using CakePHP 1.2, you need to change:

```
$this->Auth->allow('home','register','activate','forgot','reset','_sendEmail','reset');
```

to

```
$this->Auth->allow(array('home','register','activate','forgot','reset','_sendEmail','reset'));
```

Notice the added "array()" in the allow function.

Comment: are you including var $components = array('Auth')?

In addition, I found this article to be a good solution to not using ACL:
http://www.studiocanaria.com/articles/cakephp_auth_component_users_groups_permissions_revisited

Comment: interesting...I will look through this article, and yes I have set the components variable

Comment: Passing an array is not necessary.  Look at the core function, you will see that it checks the number of arguments via func_get_args(), parsing all values as strings if that's how the app calls it.

Comment: @Matt - I guess they've changed the code since I read that article mentioned in earlier comments (http://www.studiocanaria.com/articles/cakephp_auth_component_users_groups_permissions_revisited). Oddly enough, when I take out that extra array, my code no longer works. When I put it back in, the code works.... I'm on 1.2.5