# Authentication component in CakePHP doesn't work

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I'm having some issues with the authentication component. Every time I try to login in with a user (I've checked that user exists in the database with correct params), my application throws me a failure login message.

I have two models, Accounts and Employees, where one Employee belongsTo Account, and one Account hasOne Employee. I save the data with saveAssociated(), and everything is ok in the database, but it's impossible to login.

I've been searching for solutions, and repeating the CookBook tutorials once and another, and I can't find what I'm doing wrong.

Here is some code:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
public $components = array(
    'DebugKit.Toolbar',
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'accounts', 'action' => 'login'),
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'snippets', 'action' => 'index'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'snippets', 'action' => 'index'),
        'authorize' => array('Controller')));

public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'accounts', 'action' => 'login');
    $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
        AuthComponent::ALL => array(
            'userModel' => 'Account',
            'fields' => array('username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password')),
        'Basic',
        'Form');
    $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');
```

My login function:

```
public function login() {
    if($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Welcome'));
            return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'snippets', 'action' => 'index'));
            //return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Wrong password or email'), 'default', array(), 'auth');
    }
}
```

Please, someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong? If you need to see some other code sections, tell me.

Thanks!

Comment: check this [ans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959050/why-wont-the-auth-component-username-password-login-automagic-work-as-expecte?rq=1),if you still get error then try to add new user.

Comment: I've checked the answers but I can't find a solution. I've changed the name for my 'accounts' table to 'users', but I cannot login.

Answer (score 0):

When Using ControllerAuthorize `'authorize' => array('Controller')` you need to implement an `isAuthorized()` method that returns a boolean in your AppController.

```
 public function isAuthorized($user = null) {
    // Any registered user can access public functions
    if (empty($this->request->params['admin'])) {
        return true;
    }

    // Only admins can access admin functions
    if (isset($this->request->params['admin'])) {
        return (bool)($user['role'] === 'admin');
    }

    // Default deny
    return false;
}
```

You can check [the Auth Section of the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html) the docs for more info, search for "Using ControllerAuthorize"

Comment: Yep, I had already added this. But even if I remove the `'authorize' => array('Controller')` and all the related `isAuthorized()` functions, I still get the error when I login.

Comment: Can you paste the error you are getting? Are your passwords hashed in your database?

Comment: Ok, it's solved. The problem was with field names. I had 'name' as 'username', so the magic didn't work, even if I use the `AuthComponent::ALL` array for providing the field name. Do I need to change anything else if I want to use different fields for 'username' and 'password'?

Comment: Yes, the fields key on `AuthComponent::ALL` `'fields' => array('username' => 'name')`

Comment: That's what I did in my code, but it's when it didn't work. I'll try again.